# Обращение к свойству объекта внутри объекта d3.nest

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Всем хорошего дня! У меня возникла проблема - нужно вывести значения свойств объектов, которые являются сами частью объекта. То есть, есть json-файл, сгруппированный по свойству organ, а затем по свойству disease, но когда я пытаюсь извлечь значение disease, извлекается не само значение disease, а вот то, что приложено.[image] 
По количеству сходится , но значение не отображается.

```
function importData() {
d3.json('data/mydata.json', function (data)
         {

            var canvas = d3.select('.importData')
                           .data(data)
                           .append('svg')
                           .attr('width', 1000) 
                           .attr('height', 700);
             var disease = d3.nest() 
                             .key(function(d) { return d.organ;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
                             .key(function(d) { return d.disease;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
                             .entries(data);    

canvas.selectAll('text') // Описание визуализации
                        .data(disease)
                        .enter()
                        .append('text')
                        .attr('fill', '#000000')
                        .attr('y', function (d, i) {return i * 80 + 70;}) 
                        .attr('x', 10)
                        .text(function (d) {
                                    return d.values;
                        })
})}
```